# Does Visual F# have smart/RESTART?

Tags: f#

I am trying to find out if it is possible to replace parts of an older applications built in T-SQL with Visual F#?

How do F# work with smart/RESTART? Will I have to work with a design pattern to ensure that I will never lose data?

Thank You!

Comment: I think there are 2 separate questions here, SO generally tries to keep one question per "question" :)  Also, it *might* also depend on if you are referring to [Visual F# or F#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2015/10/23/a-letter-about-quot-f-quot-and-quot-visual-f-quot.aspx).

Comment: you have an application build in T-SQL? :o (also: what is smart/RESTART)?

Comment: It's a big Legacy system and big parts are in T-SQL and smart/RESTART is way to make sure you don’t lose data if your server dies in the middle of a batch job.  https://www.relarc.com/product/smartrestart